# Integration of the Mono2micro interface on my web application

Tags: javascript, angular, api, integration

I am currently looking for a solution to integrate the mono2micro graphics and their interactions on my web application. I would like to be able to give input of execution traces and use cases for example and that I have access to the mono2micro graphics.

I saw that there was a way to do that with Angular or with API calls but I can't find the GitHub page of the project to see the API calls.

Any help would be welcome!
Have a nice day.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.